# Passing Image Through Intent. getting error: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "null"

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-glide

I have two `Activities` in my `Application`, I want to pass `Image title` and `image` itself through intent to `second activity` of the same `application`. But I am getting the following error:
`java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "null"`  at below line

```
Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra("Image"))).into(imageView);
```

**Activity 1 code:**

```
 public void cardClicked(final  Sport  currentSport){
            itemCard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(context, DetailActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("Image",R.drawable.img_baseball);
                        intent.putExtra("Name",currentSport.getTitle());

                        context.startActivity(intent);
                    }
            });


        }
```

**Second Activity Code:**

```
private ImageView imageView;
    private TextView nameView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);
        imageView = findViewById(R.id.tv_image);
        nameView = findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        nameView.setText(String.valueOf(intent.getStringExtra("Name")));
       Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra("Image"))).into(imageView);

    }
```

Comment: Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra("Image")?)).into(imageView);

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Try this`Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(Integer.parseInt(intent.getIntExtra("Image",-1))).into(imageView);`

Comment: Check that intent.getStringExtra("Image") is not null

Comment: Ahh its woking ..... Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `intent.getStringExtra(String)` although you expect an int. So correct would be to use `intent.getIntExtra(String, int)`.

Comment: this could have been a comment.